# In wordpress customizer api adding div wrap to control

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

As here is a [ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37439) about input_attrs class not working for some controls .

I want to know if I can wrap some wordpress customize control inside a div ?

Can I do something like

```
$wp_customize->add_control( $this->slug . '_style[heading_text_decoration]', array(
            'label'    => __('Text Decoration'),
            'type'     => 'checkbox',
            'section' => $this->slug . '_text_style',
            'priority' => 16,
            'input_attrs' => array(
                'before' => '<div class="my-wrap">',
                'class' => 'section-style-all-heading',
                'after' => '</div>'
            ),
        ) );
```

or

```
$wp_customize->add_control( $this->slug . '_style[heading_text_decoration]', array(
            'label'    => __('Text Decoration'),
            'type'     => 'checkbox',
            'section' => $this->slug . '_text_style',
            'priority' => 16,
            'input_attrs' => array(
                'wrap' => '<div class="my-wrap"></div>',
                'class' => 'section-style-all-heading',
            ),
        ) );
```

or any other way to do it ?

Comment: Its the div really necessary?

Comment: @DavidLee I want to separate the controls and want to show and hide using javascript.

Comment: you dont have access to the files that add the controls? separate with CSS?

Comment: @DavidLee consider a section having 15 controls now I want to organize those by 3 groups and only one group will visible that will be chosen by select box now, if I can not add class or wrap, how I will separate them ?

Comment: that can be done in 2 ways and you dont need `input_attrs` since its at the control level, this is a entire new question.

Comment: @DavidLee not different, my target is to found a way to wrap as can not add class and after that, I know how I will solve it .

Answer (score 0):

As the ticket says, `input_attrs` is not working for:

> checkboxes, textareas, and other non-fallthrough cases

to have the wrapper you would have to create your own custom control and add the div in the render part, or go the hackish way with JavaScript.